# google App script - replace formula with static values if condition is met

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script

Trying to come up with a Google App Script that replaces formula outputs with static values for previous weeks.

Here is Sample Google Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GaqGBG4YcSihlP10weIr7tnGGgNSvf9XcftEoYeS4DY/edit#gid=0

Spreadsheet has 'Report' Sheet which is updated once a week (new data are overwritten) and cell B3 gets total number of cutomers from this report.
'Summary' Sheet, where row B29:BA29 are calendar weeks. 
Cell B5 - current CW number for report.
Row B32:BA32 contains weekly data on number of customers that should be picked up from Report Sheet.

Since Report is always updating would like to hardcode formula results for past weeks.

Tried with loop and w/o it. Tried getValues, Logger, setValues. Also tried copyValuesToRange. Either nothing is replaced or all weeks get static values even future ones.

```
function freeze() {

var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX').getSheetByName('Summary');

var cw = sss.getRange('B5').getValue;//current week

var weeks = sss.getRange('B29:BA29').getValues(); // all weeks

    for (var i=0; i<weeks.length; i++) {
    // alternatively tried this loop 
    //  for (var i=0; i<weeks[0].length; i=i+1)

         if (weeks < cw) 

      {  var dered = sss.getRange(32,2,1,27);

         dered.copyValuesToRange(sss,2,27,32,32);

}}}
```

or another code

```
function freeze() {

var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX');

var cw = sss.getSheetByName('Summary').getRange('B5').getValue;

var weeks = sss.getSheetByName('Summary').getRange('B29:BA29').getValues(); 

 var dered = sss.getSheetByName('Summary').getRange('B32:BA32');

 var deredvalues = dered.getValues();

      if (weeks < cw) {

  var deredsum = msred.setValues(deredvalues);

} }
```

or like this

```
 function freeze() {

  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX');

  var cw = sss.getSheetByName('Summary').getRange('B5').getValue;

  var weeks = sss.getSheetByName('Summary').getRange('B29:BA29').getValues(); 

  var dered = sss.getSheetByName('Summary').getRange('B32:BA32');

    if (weeks < cw) {

   var deredvalues = dered.getValues();

     Logger.log(deredvalues)

        dered.setValues(deredvalues);

  } }
```

Either nothing is replaced or all weeks get static values even future ones. Would be grateful for ideas.

Comment: Could you share a copy of the sheet with dummy data for what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @ross updated my question with a link to Spreadsheet. Thanks

Comment: I can't see the "report" sheet you're talking about - is it missing from the copy you shared?

Comment: @ross ReportRed and ReportYellow

Comment: Where are your formulas?

Comment: @ross in row 32 in Summary Sheet. Currently formula starts in cell Z32. Previous weeks I hardcoded formula output manually

Comment: Please explain a little bit more in detail what you want to achieve. So far I can tell you that I see some bugs in your code. E.g. with var weeks = sss.getSheetByName('Summary').getRange('B29:BA29').getValues(); and if (weeks < cw) you try to compare an array of values to a number - this is not possible. Careful with: dered = sss.getRange(32,2,1,27); dered.copyValuesToRange(sss,2,27,32,32); THOSE RANGES HAVE DIFFERENT DIMENSIONS! And your msred is not defined. I can help you more if I understand what exactly you are trying to achieve and see a spreadsheet with formulas.

Comment: @ziganotschka here is a sample google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vy1k_ejwxA4DJPqo_Pa0b5kXSkvE44MHRPR3lNF3wCw/edit#gid=1775744309 Summary sheet has numbers for all weeks. US Category 1 and Category 2 are used to post weekly reports. I need data from cells B2 and B3 were copied (as values) to Summary sheet rows 33,34,36,37 of correspondent weeks. I cant paste simple formula like ='US Category1'!B2 because this cells change every week. Need to keep records of historical data 
Thanks for pointing out issues with ranges!

Comment: I hope my answer addressed your issue correctly?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure you should follow to implement your desired functionality:

1. Check in sheet `Summary`, cell `B5` which calendar week it is
2. Find the column assigned to the respective calendar week
3. Get the values from the cells `B2` and `B3` from sheets `Us Category1` and `Category2`
4. Paste the values in the corresponding rows in sheet `Summary` - in the column that corresponds to the  current calendar week

This is what it could look like, based on the script file bound to the spreadsheet you added in the comments:

```
function logUS() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Vy1k_ejwxA4DJPqo_Pa0b5kXSkvE44MHRPR3lNF3wCw');
  var country = "US";
  var summary=ss.getSheetByName('Summary');
  var cw = summary.getRange('B5').getValue();
  var cat1 = ss.getSheetByName('US Category1').getRange('B2').getValue();
  var cat1cancel = ss.getSheetByName('US Category1').getRange('B3').getValue();
  var cat2 = ss.getSheetByName('US Category2').getRange('B2').getValue();
  var cat2cancel = ss.getSheetByName('US Category2').getRange('B3').getValue();

  var ts = ss.getSheetByName('CopyValues').appendRow([country+cw,cw,cat1,cat2,cat1cancel,cat2cancel]); 
  var columnNumbers=summary.getLastColumn()-1; 
  var weekRange=summary.getRange(31,2, 1, columnNumbers);
  for(i=0;i<columnNumbers; i++)
   {
    if(summary.getRange(31,(2+i)).getValue()==cw)
       {
       summary.getRange(33,(2+i)).setValue(cat1);
       summary.getRange(34,(2+i)).setValue(cat2);
       summary.getRange(36,(2+i)).setValue(cat1cancel);
       summary.getRange(37,(2+i)).setValue(cat2cancel);
      }   
   } 
}
```